# What literary techniques are evident in this quote?

Tags: technique, figures-of-speech, rhetoric

What literary techniques are evident in the following quote?

> I read each bullet scar in the Quai stonework
>   With an eerie familiar feeling,
>   And started at the stricken, sunny exposure of pavement

Comment: Hi Jaydon; we've got certain restrictions on homework-type questions. In a nutshell, tell us your own progress and your attempts to answer the question. Don't just ask us the question you're supposed to answer; **tell us why you're having trouble answering it.** More details on homework question netiquette at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Comment: Also, you should have not deleted the migrated question http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30388/literary-technique

Comment: Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet.

Comment: @Roland: you rang?

Comment: @Lauren, haha sort of :D - your name partly inspired my comment (I was going to make it before seeing your name but then seeing your name sealed it ;). I wanted to point out in a subtle way: "Wrong kind of question for this site, don't expect a reasonable answer."

Comment: Still hasn't been revised according to homework guidelines; I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

The only technique I can really suggest is one of [alliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration), which is essentially the repetition of the same sound due to certain syllables within words, which form a pattern or beat of sorts, imposing a shape on the lines.

If you re-read the final line and place emphasis on the syllables, you notice "star-ted", "strick-en", and "sun-ny"; it seems the author is trying to put particular emphasis on the "s"-like syllables (the use of "scar" and "stone-work" in the first line suggests a link to the third due to this technique).

A similar technique is used in the second line with "fam-il-i-ar feel-ing" (the "f" sounds).

Comment: def: *Repeating the same letter or sound at the beginning of adjacent or closely connected words* - therefore "ex-po-sure" does not qualify; you might also check out assonance

Comment: @Unreason was thinking more of the 'sure' portion, but you are probably right.

Comment: @Craig Sefton, exactly: '-sure' portion is not at the beginning, which is requirement for alliteration.

Comment: @Unreason actually, in poetry it doesn't matter if the consonant is at the beginning or not.

Comment: @Craig Sefton, reference? (are you sure you are not thinking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_consonance)

Comment: @Unreason from the Wikipedia article on alliteration: Alliteration has historically developed largely through poetry, in which it more narrowly refers to the repetition of a consonant in any syllables that, according to the poem's meter, are stressed

Comment: @Craig Sefton, thanks, learned something. Still :), that particular example you should remove: 1) see more precise requirements in poetry  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliterative_verse#Alliteration  2) stress is on ik-*spoh*-zher not ik-spoh-*zher* 3) *suhn*-ee does not alliterate with ik-*spoh*-zher

Answer (score 1):

Pretentiousness.